# How to save in nhibernate?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I am confused about how to setup my mapping so things save and I don't have to put references to everything.

```
public class TableAMapping : ClassMap<TableA>
    {
        public TableAMapping()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();
            Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable().NvarcharWithMaxSize(); ;

            References(x => x.Country).Not.Nullable();
            HasMany(x => x.Bonuses).Cascade.All();
            HasManyToMany(x => x.AvailableFeatures).Cascade.All();
        }
    }

 public class BonusMapping : ClassMap<Bonus>
    {
        public BonusMapping()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();


            Map(x => x.Amount).Not.Nullable().Precision(10).Scale(2);

            References(x => x.BonusType).Not.Nullable();
            References(x => x.TableA).Not.Nullable();

        }
    }

      public class AvailableFeatureMapping : ClassMap<AvailableFeature>
    {
        public AvailableFeatureMapping()
        {
            Id(x => x.Id).GeneratedBy.GuidComb();

            Map(x => x.Name).Not.Nullable().NvarcharWithMaxSize();

            HasManyToMany(x => x.TableAs);

        }
    }
```

In my code I do something like this

```
TableA a = new TableA();
a.Name = "test";
a.Country = session.Load<Country>(1);

foreach(var b in bonuesVm)
{
   Bonus bonus = new Bonus();
   bonus.Amount = b.Amount;
   bonus.BonusType = sesson.Load<BonusType>(b.bonusTypeId);

   a.Bounus.add(bonus);
}

foreach(var avaliable in avaliableVm)
{
   AvaliableFeatures features = new AvaliableFeatures();
   features.Name = avaliable.Name;

   a.AvaliableFeatures.Add(features);
}

session.Save(a);
transaction.Commit();
```

I stripped out stuff like unit of work and I am not showing what is in the vm as I don't think it is necessary as they are just properties. This should give you and idea of what I am doing.

The mapping always confuses me. I never sure if I need to use `inverse` or `cascade.SaveUpdate()`

with my current setup I get this error

```
NHibernate.PropertyValueException was unhandled by user code
  Message=not-null property references a null or transient value Framework.Domain.Bonus.TableA
  Source=NHibernate
  EntityName=.Framework.Domain.Bonus
  PropertyName=TableA
```

So it want's me to put a reference to TableA in the Bonus object. Is there away to not do this? Or does it have to be done no matter what. I would have hopped that since it is in the TableA object that it could figure it out from that. Just seems kinda pointless to have to put TableA into Bonus which is already in TableA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have created a bi directional link, but your object creation has not yet taken care of that. Just assign the tableA property to the bonus and things should start saving...

Comment: Well that is what I was wondering if it is possible to not have to assign TableA to Bonus but I guess it is not.

Comment: Ah, ok.. Well, no indeed. Nhibernate is an object relational mapper. It would be strange if it would save object graphs not in sync with the models.